# ChiSqSelector picks the wrong feature?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, feature-selection, apache-spark-ml, chi-squared

I copy pasted [this example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-features.html#chisqselector) from the docs in my `Spark 2.3.0` Shell.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.ChiSqSelector
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

val data = Seq(
  (7, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0, 18.0, 1.0), 1.0),
  (8, Vectors.dense(0.0, 1.0, 12.0, 0.0), 0.0),
  (9, Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0, 15.0, 0.1), 0.0)
)

val df = spark.createDataset(data).toDF("id", "features", "clicked")

val selector = new ChiSqSelector()
  .setNumTopFeatures(1)
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setLabelCol("clicked")
  .setOutputCol("selectedFeatures")

val selectorModel = selector.fit(df)
val result = selectorModel.transform(df)
result.show
+---+------------------+-------+----------------+
| id|          features|clicked|selectedFeatures|
+---+------------------+-------+----------------+
|  7|[0.0,0.0,18.0,1.0]|    1.0|          [18.0]|
|  8|[0.0,1.0,12.0,0.0]|    0.0|          [12.0]|
|  9|[1.0,0.0,15.0,0.1]|    0.0|          [15.0]|
+---+------------------+-------+----------------+

selectorModel.selectedFeatures
res2: Array[Int] = Array(2)
```

`ChiSqSelector` mistakenly picks `feature 2` instead of `feature 3` (Feature 3 should be correct based on the docs and common sense)

Answer (score 1):

Chi-Squared feature selection [operates on categorical data](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-features.html#chisqselector)

> `ChiSqSelector` stands for Chi-Squared feature selection. It operates on labeled data with categorical features

Therefore both features are equally good (though we should stress that both features can be used to derive trivial perfect classifiers even if used as continuous variables) .

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors => OldVectors}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics

Statistics.chiSqTest(sc.parallelize(data.map { 
  case (_, v, l) => LabeledPoint(l, OldVectors.fromML(v)) 
})).slice(2, 4)
```

```
Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.ChiSqTestResult] =
Array(Chi squared test summary:
method: pearson
degrees of freedom = 2
statistic = 3.0
pValue = 0.22313016014843035
No presumption against null hypothesis: the occurrence of the outcomes is statistically independent.., Chi squared test summary:
method: pearson
degrees of freedom = 2
statistic = 3.0000000000000004
pValue = 0.22313016014843035
No presumption against null hypothesis: the occurrence of the outcomes is statistically independent..)
```

and the results of the tests are consistent with other tools. For example in R ([used as a reference for selector tests](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6ad8d4c375772c0c907c25837de762b5b9266a8e/mllib/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/ChiSqSelectorSuite.scala#L84-L98)):

```
y <- as.factor(c("1.0", "0.0", "0.0"))
x2 <- as.factor(c("18.0", "12.0", "15.0"))
x3 <- as.factor(c("1.0", "0.0", "0.1"))

chisq.test(table(x2, y))
```

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  table(x2, y)
X-squared = 3, df = 2, p-value = 0.2231

Warning message:
In chisq.test(table(x2, y)) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

```r
chisq.test(table(x3, y))
```

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  table(x3, y)
X-squared = 3, df = 2, p-value = 0.2231

Warning message:
In chisq.test(table(x3, y)) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Since selector [just sorts data by p-value](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6ad8d4c375772c0c907c25837de762b5b9266a8e/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/ChiSqSelector.scala#L261-L263) and [`sortBy` is stable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35369243/10465355), it is first come, first served. If you switch the order of feature, the other one will be selected.

Comment: Hi @Gevorg. Please let me know if you need any additional explanations.